# How to style Input type button in html

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a following fragment of code which inserts a Click Button and open a google page in my CRM. How can i style my button. The button is present in the input tab dow below.What are the opptions. to maka a button more smoother and superb

```
<script>

function openLink(target){

        window.open('https://google.co.in','_blank');
}

function addCustomButton()
{



               var mergeNode = document.getElementById("BTN_TB_AccountForm_MergeWizard").parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;

               var parent=mergeNode.parentNode;



               //BTN_TB_AccountForm_MergeWizard is the ID of the Merge Button on the ActionForm Bar


               //Create a TD node and attach a buttom element.

               var td2 = document.createElement("td");
               td2.innerHTML="<input type=button  value=Click onclick=\"openLink()\">";

               //Append Child
               parent.insertBefore(td2,mergeNode.nextSibling);


        }

}

setTimeout ( "addCustomButton()", 1000 ); // To be sure the Action Bar is loaded
</script>
```

Comment: you can use CSS for styling.. create CSS class and add it to button..

Comment: Try googling about CSS... Maybe "_css button smooth edges_"

Answer (score 0):

you can style it using the:

```
input {
   your css here
}
```

or to be more specific use:

```
input[type=button]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set css class of button:

```
<input type="button" class="MyButton" value="Click" onclick="openLink();">
```

and set inner html of `td` like this:

```
td2.innerHTML="<input type='button' class='MyButton' value='Click' onclick=\"openLink();\">";
```

CSS (this style only for demostration you can set your specific or according your requriment):

```
.MyButton{
   color: #ffffff;
   background-color: #1EAA49;
  *background-color: #1EAA49;
   border-color: #4cae4c;
}
```